# Set up database for integration testing with Jenkins in Docker

Tags: mysql, docker, git, jenkins, continuous-integration

**Background:**
I was following [Downloading and running Jenkins in Docker](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/#downloading-and-running-jenkins-in-docker) to setup `Jenkins` Server. Used following parameter to run `Docker`.

```
docker run \
  -u root \
  --rm \  
  -d \ 
  -p 8080:8080 \ 
  -p 50000:50000 \ 
  -v jenkins-data:/var/jenkins_home \ 
  -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \ 
  jenkinsci/blueocean
```

The build is running successfully, however, when it comes to `Integration Test` stage, a `MySQL` database is required.
The plan is [Using multiple containers](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/#using-multiple-containers), while my `Jenkinsfile` is as following:

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        docker {
            image 'maven:3-alpine'
            args '-v /root/.m2:/root/.m2'
        }
    }
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            when {
                changeRequest()
            }
            steps {
                sh 'mvn -B -DskipTests clean package'
            }
        }
        stage('Test') { 
            agent {
                docker {
                image 'mysql/mysql-server'
                args '--name some-mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password -d'}
            }
            steps {
                sh 'mvn test -DforkCount=0'
                sh '''
                    docker exec some-mysql sh -c 'exec mysql < ./db/dump.sql
                    '''
            }
            post {
                always {
                    junit 'target/surefire-reports/*.xml' 
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `./db/dump.sql` is in the same git repository with `Jenkinsfile` in `db` subdirectory.

**Problem:**

```
[workspace@2] Running shell script
+ docker inspect -f . mysql/mysql-server /var/jenkins_home/jobs/myproject/branches/master/workspace@2@tmp/durable-77d559d6/script.sh: line 1: docker: not found
[Pipeline] sh
[workspace@2] Running shell script
+ docker pull mysql/mysql-server /var/jenkins_home/jobs/myproject/branches/master/workspace@2@tmp/durable-21da0ff2/script.sh: ...   line 1: docker: not found
ERROR: script returned exit code 127
Finished: FAILURE
```

Since running as root, the privilege should not be the problem, right?
[Using Docker with Pipeline](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/#using-docker-with-pipeline) provided several solutions, would other solution be much easier to set up the `Integration Test` environment?

Answer (score 1):

The console output describes the error:

```
line 1: docker: not found
```

The shell script cannot find docker, likely because Docker is not installed on your Jenkins executor.  (The Jenkins Docker plugin does not guarantee that Docker will be available to Jenkins-external processes, such as shell scripts.)

Comment: So what would be your suggestion?

Comment: Install Docker on your Jenkins executor

Comment: Is `agent` `docker` part able to handle it? Feel install docker in docker is not a good idea in instinct.

Comment: I plan to write a `Dockfile` build FROM MySQL and Jenkins would that  
 works?

Answer (score 0):

Docker client is not installed on the container. Either install docker or use a image of jenkins + docker. Also docker daemon of host machine is used and need to mount it.

Below commands should help:

1. `docker volume create jenkins-master-data`
2. `docker run --name jenkins-master -u 0 --privileged -p 8080:8080 -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v jenkins-master-data:/var/jenkins_home gustavoapolinario/jenkins-docker`